# Converting multiple rows through cast function in SQL

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, sql-server-2014, sqldatatypes, sql-query-store

I have a `database table` with `name`, `address`, and `monthly account expense` as column information for every single month.

I want to add expenses from `month1` to `month12` data of an `accounts` table but it is in `varchar` data type, I want to convert it into `float` data type and also use a logical expression in the query that gets the `SUM` of all the expenses (`month 1` + `month 2` +...`month12`) should be greater than `10,000`.

But I am not able to solve this problem as the query is not working and am getting errors

Kindly check this query and let me know of any changes

```
SELECT name
      ,address
      ,CAST(([month1] + [month2]...[month12] AS float) AS 'total expense'
FROM Accounts_Table
WHERE name LIKE 'a%'
GROUP BY name, address, 'total expense'
HAVING 'total expense' > 10000
```

Some pointers will be great to work around this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you added and converted the `month` columns was incorrect.

Also you won't be able to call the alias of `[Total Expense]` in the `HAVING` clause on the same query where you declared it. Use a `SUBQUERY`.

See below.

```
SELECT [name]
      ,[address]
      ,[Total Expense]
FROM (
    SELECT [name]
          ,[address]
          ,CAST([month1] AS float) +
           CAST([month2] AS float) +
           CAST([month3] AS float) +
           CAST([month4] AS float) +
           CAST([month5] AS float) +
           CAST([month6] AS float) +
           CAST([month7] AS float) +
           CAST([month8] AS float) +
           CAST([month9] AS float) +
           CAST([month10] AS float) +
           CAST([month11] AS float) +
           CAST([month12] AS float) AS [Total Expense]
    FROM [Accounts_Table]
    WHERE [name] LIKE 'a%') AS [src]
GROUP BY [name]
        ,[address]
        ,[Total Expense]
HAVING [Total Expense] > 10000
```

Comment: Thanks @CurseStacker

Answer (score 0):

You have to Convert Each varchar column to Float Before Adding it.
Have a look for Explaining

```
, (CAST( [month1] as float) + CAST([month2] as float)... CAST([month12] as Float))  AS 
   'total expense'
```